# Windows Explorer Crumb-Bar Control

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, windows-vista, explorer

I am seeking a, preferably free, crumb-bar control for my app. For those that do now know what it is, it is the address bar on the top of explorer:

[image: crumb bar]

If anyone knows of any free or paid control libraries that have this, please answer.

Comment: Please use google for searches like these.  Second hit: http://www.google.com/#hl=en&expIds=17259,25856,25900,26440,26512&sugexp=ldymls&tok=2V088_yVVE7V_vaoEka4Lg&xhr=t&q=crumbbar+control&cp=16&pf=p&sclient=psy&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=crumbbar+control&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=280187d6f0589da0

Comment: Amusingly, Hans, the second hit has now been pushed down to the third hit: this question on StackOverflow is now the top hit! :-)

Comment: I've consulted Google. I came across this before: http://www.devcomponents.com/dotnetbar/BreadCrumbHorizontalTreeControl.aspx But the dll is 4mb and that is kind of bloated for one control. |:

Answer (score 0):

You might want to create your own control that would do the same (given that you pass a correct file path that can be divided in folders).

There is a **MSDN Magazine** article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163764.aspx) that shows how to implement a breadcrumb control.

Even though you are using C#, it'll be fairly easy to convert the VB.NET code in the article to C#.

Comment: That's not entirely how I want it to look. I also want it to be editable, like how you can edit the address in explorer. Thanks, though.